# Ubuntu 18.04.2 periodically disables all devices

Tags: 14.04, 18.04, debian, fedora

I'm using Advantech SOM-7567 mainboard. Previous OS was ubuntu server 14.04. I tried to upgrade to Ubuntu Serer 18.04.2 (ubuntu-18.04.2-server-amd64.iso). During install the display and USB devices disconnecting periodically. 
It looks like short sleep and wake, e.g. 30 sec working, 15 sec not working and again. I reinstalled 14.04 and rechecked the issue - older version does not have it.
I also tried Fedora 29 and Debian 9.8 - same periodic stucks.

What can be the reason of a such behaviour of Ubuntu 18.04.2?

Comment: Is it just during the installation?  Also, have you tried any other versions, such as 16.04 or 18.10?

Comment: No. I Have to use 18.04

Answer (score 0):

I see glitches of suspend system in dmesg. To fix it I disabled sleep and hibernate with the command:
`systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target`.
Restart logind.service or reboot to apply.